# Measuring Voltage of Unknown Type

Tags: ac, dc

My circuit is almost identical to [the Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aRC_Filter.png) but with 5V in, 1pF cap, 4 pieces of IN4004 diodes. I am not certain whether it is AC or DC here and there (actually I do but not want to break my multimeter). Is there some safe way to test its type? My multimeter has only separate modes for AC and DC but not a common mode for both of them. **So how to find out unknown voltage type?**

Comment: Are you referring to voltage here? The wikipedia article's circuit assumes AC voltage, as this rectifier circuit 'converts' ac to dc voltage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you set your multimeter to DC(V) and then measure an AC(V) it will not cause damage, neither will the opposite.

If you measure it with both, and one says 5 V, then that is what signal you have. 5V AC wave will not be anything on DC measurement, but will be 5V with AC turned on.

Comment: as a side note, if they mean 5VAC rms, which often is the case, then the actual wave is going to be 5V*squareroot(2) in magnitude.

Comment: This is true if the waveform is a sinusoid.  If the waveform is something else (e.g. squarewave or triangle or highly distorted), then the sqrt(2) factor isn't correct.  Furthermore, one also has to be careful about the meter -- true RMS meters actually compute an RMS value and will give "correct" readings for non-sinewaves.  Lower cost ac meters assume a sinewave and just apply to 1/sqrt(2) factor to the peak.

Comment: @madrivereric, interesting on RMS adjustment. I always use a scope unless I have a specific reason.